# Unity AudioSource.Play has noise

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, noise

I have multiple piano keys with the AudioSource Component, if I press one key repeatedly the sound starts with a tick noise that is not in the original sound clip.

I tried changing the audio clips and set Doppler Factor to 0 but nothing works.

I could manage it by instantiating the key while its playing and the noise is gone now but if I play multiple keys by moving my finger over them I get a "Hall Reverb" effect and its a little expensive too.

```
         if (go.GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying)
         {
             AudioSource Note = Instantiate(go.GetComponent<AudioSource>(), Clones);
             Note.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
             Note.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
             Note.Play();
             Destroy(Note.gameObject, 2);
         }
         else
         {
             go.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
         }
```

I tried PlayOneShot() and it had the exact same effect like the code above.

Could you help me? I am using Unity 2018.2.14f1.

Comment: What file type is it? If you're using mp3 some data is added to the beginning/end, I believe. Try using wav instead

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks to me that you want to play a note, even when your audiosource is already playing.

Instead of duplicating an existing gameobject (which is prone to errors, use a prefab instead) you can play an audio clip at a point.

```
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, transform.position);
```

You would need to add a public variable that takes in the target clip into your script.

Comment: Here is a link to the Unity docs on that function: [AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply and yes that is what i want, i tried AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint and everything seems fine but i have still the Reverb problem if I play multiple keys by moving my finger over them